# Android app takes lot of time to start

Tags: android, performance

I've an Android app. In the `onCreate()` method of splash screen I've add

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(SplashActivity.APP_NAME, "Executing post-delayed code");
        }
    , 100);
```

So, what I expect is that this code will get executed after 100ms after onCreate is exited.

But I can see that my app is taking 3 seconds after onCreate() to execute the post-delayed code (also UI appears after 3seconds):

```
08-30 19:00:45.614 4559-4559/com.example.my I/My Example: OnCreate is exited
08-30 19:00:45.621 4559-4683/com.example.my D/OpenGLRenderer:   Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-30 19:00:45.654 4559-4683/com.example.my I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 166ada0, Ifd751822f5
                                                            Build Date                       : 01/26/16
                                                            OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                            Local Branch                     : AU12_SBA
                                                            Remote Branch                    : 
                                                            Remote Branch                    : 
                                                            Reconstruct Branch               : 

**08-30 19:00:45.662** 4559-4683/com.example.my I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized     EGL, version 1.4

**08-30 19:00:48.646** 4559-4559/com.example.my I/My Example: Executing post-delayed code
```

Can someone please tell me why an app can take 3 seconds after onCreate() to execute post-delayed code and UI to start appearing?

Please suggest me tips on how I can optimize this time?

**One more question**, does handler.postDelayed() execute after onStart() / UI is shown?

Comment: are you sure that onCreate is exiting?

Comment: I suppose its taking about 100 ms only. Try putting a log at the beginning of your `onCreate()`.

Comment: @Shaishav updated logs when onCreate exited.

Comment: @Sanoop signed apk took lesser time, but still it is significant.

Comment: @lelloman yes, updated logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to add little larger timeout because even default android studio template set timeout time to 300 ms.
You can see the comment in android fullscreen application template

```
/**
 * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
 * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
 */
private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
```

Also much depends on your layout because Android draws it in main thread and if your UI have much nesting levels or hard drawing code it can also reduce performance.

Comment: It depended on the layout. I was loading a splash screen background image which was in KBs.